# Apache2 not starting : libaprutil-1.so.0 => not found

Tags: apache2

I was installing apache2 on Ubuntu 13.10, but after installation I tried to run apache showin error:

```
$ sudo ./httpd start
./httpd: error while loading shared libraries: libaprutil-1.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried solutions given on web, none of them working, please help!!

```
$ ldd httpd
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff05fe000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f60741a5000)
    libaprutil-1.so.0 => not found
    libapr-1.so.0 => /usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-1.so.0 (0x00007f6073f71000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f6073d54000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f607398c000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f6073786000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f6073582000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f60743d9000)
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install libaprutil1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first try configure dynamic linker run-time bindings

```
ldconfig
```

If this don't solve your problem try to reinstall libaprutil1

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libaprutil1
```